# aws credentials error while using dynamic inventory

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible, aws-cli

When i try to run an ansible playbook i am getting an aws credential authentication error. I did aws configure and also tried with creating credentials file manually, but still the same error, but i am able to execute aws commands.

```
ansible 2.4.0.0
  config file = /home/centos/infrastructure/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = [u'/home/centos/.ansible/plugins/modules', u'/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/bin/ansible
  python version = 2.7.5 (default, Aug  4 2017, 00:39:18) [GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-16)]


[DEPRECATION WARNING]: DEFAULT_SUDO_USER option, In favor of become which is a generic framework . This feature will be removed in
version 2.8. Deprecation warnings can be disabled by setting deprecation_warnings=False in ansible.cfg.
 [WARNING]:  * Failed to parse /home/centos/infrastructure/production/ec2.py with script plugin: Inventory script
(/home/centos/infrastructure/production/ec2.py) had an execution error: Traceback (most recent call last):   File
"/home/centos/infrastructure/production/ec2.py", line 1600, in <module>     Ec2Inventory()   File
"/home/centos/infrastructure/production/ec2.py", line 193, in __init__     self.do_api_calls_update_cache()   File
"/home/centos/infrastructure/production/ec2.py", line 525, in do_api_calls_update_cache     self.get_instances_by_region(region)
File "/home/centos/infrastructure/production/ec2.py", line 579, in get_instances_by_region     conn = self.connect(region)   File
"/home/centos/infrastructure/production/ec2.py", line 543, in connect     conn = self.connect_to_aws(ec2, region)   File
"/home/centos/infrastructure/production/ec2.py", line 568, in connect_to_aws     conn = module.connect_to_region(region,
**connect_args)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/ec2/__init__.py", line 66, in connect_to_region     return
region.connect(**kw_params)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/regioninfo.py", line 188, in connect     return
self.connection_cls(region=self, **kw_params)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/ec2/connection.py", line 102, in __init__
profile_name=profile_name)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/connection.py", line 1057, in __init__
profile_name=profile_name)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/connection.py", line 568, in __init__     host, config,
self.provider, self._required_auth_capability())   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/auth.py", line 882, in get_auth_handler
'Check your credentials' % (len(names), str(names))) boto.exception.NoAuthHandlerFound: No handler was ready to authenticate. 1
handlers were checked. ['QuerySignatureV2AuthHandler'] Check your credentials

 [WARNING]:  * Failed to parse /home/centos/infrastructure/production/ec2.py with ini plugin:
/home/centos/infrastructure/production/ec2.py:3: Error parsing host definition ''''': No closing quotation
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the easiest ways to use AWS credentials with ansible is to create a credentials file in .aws/ in your home directory and place the access key and secret access key in there (you can create multiple sets of credentials) i.e:

```
cat ~/.aws/credentials

[profile1]
aws_access_key_id = XXXXXXXXXXX
aws_secret_access_key = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

[default]
aws_access_key_id = XXXXXXXXXXX
aws_secret_access_key = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Then you execute ansible-playbook like this:

```
AWS_PROFILE=profile1 ansible-playbook -i ec2.py playbook.yml
```

AWS_PROFILE is an environment variable that you can set by doing

```
export AWS_PROFILE=profile1
```

Note that you also need an environment variable with a default AWS region for example:

```
export AWS_EC2_REGION=ap-southeast-2
```